# Flutter image and rounded border

Tags: flutter

I'm working on designing a screen where I have a block containing an image and another block underneath it with some details. I want the block underneath the image to have rounded borders only on the top-left and top-right corners, while the image should fill the corners of the block. But I cant figure out how to do this. Hope someone can help me!

What i have now:

my design now

What it must to be:

My page:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: const Color(0xFFEBEBEB),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Stack(
                      children: [
                        Image.network(
                          Uri.parse(baseurl).resolve(house.image).toString(),
                          height: 200,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          top: 35, // Adjust the top positioning as needed
                          left: 10, // Adjust the left positioning as needed
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: Navigator.of(context).pop,
                            child: SvgPicture.asset(
                              'assets/icons/ic_back.svg',
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 30,
                              height: 30,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text('\$' + house.price.toString(),
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'GothamSSm',
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                      // Set the font weight to medium
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      color: Color(0xCC000000))),
                              const SizedBox(height: 8,width: 60,),
                              SvgPicture.asset(
                                'assets/icons/ic_bed.svg',
                                width: 18,
                                height: 18,
                                color: Color(0x66000000),
                              ),
                              Text(house.bedrooms.toString(),
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'GothamSSm',
                                      fontSize: 10,
                                      color: Color(0x66000000))),
                              const SizedBox(width: 5),
                              //width for space betweens icons
                              SvgPicture.asset(
                                'assets/icons/ic_bath.svg',
                                width: 18,
                                height: 18,
                                color: Color(0x66000000),
                              ),
                              Text(house.bathrooms.toString(),
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'GothamSSm',
                                      fontSize: 10,
                                      color: Color(0x66000000))),
                              const SizedBox(width: 5),
                              SvgPicture.asset(
                                'assets/icons/ic_layers.svg',
                                width: 18,
                                height: 18,
                                color: Color(0x66000000),
                              ),
                              Text(house.size.toString(),
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'GothamSSm',
                                      fontSize: 10,
                                      color: Color(0x66000000))),
                              const SizedBox(width: 5),
                              //
                              SvgPicture.asset(
                                'assets/icons/ic_location.svg',
                                width: 18,
                                height: 18,
                                color: Color(0x66000000),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                  house.distanceFromUser != null
                                      ? '${house.distanceFromUser?.toStringAsFixed(0)} km'
                                      : '',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontFamily: 'GothamSSm',
                                      fontSize: 10,
                                      color: Color(0x66000000))),
                              // Display the distance if available, otherwise an empty string
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 20),
                          const Text(
                            'Description',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 15),
                          Text(house.description,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'GothamSSm',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  color: Color(0x66000000))),
                          const SizedBox(height: 8),
                          const Text(
                            'Location',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use Stack to achieve this.

```
SizedBox(
  height: 250,
  child: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    children: [
          Image.network(
            Uri.parse(baseurl).resolve(house.image).toString(),
            height: 200,
            width: double.infinity,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 60,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
            top: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

You can always play a bit with `fit` `height` and such attributes to achieve your exact design goal.

Comment: But if i place my whole container in the stack, my text details display all on top? i mean like in the image and i want it to display underneath the image?

Comment: Nevermind i figure it out! thanks bro the stack was key!